# How to restore savedInstanceState of fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was able to save outState as follows but was unable to restore when I land on this ***AttendanceFragment.cs*** second time.

```
 public override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        dataGotFromServer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataList);
        outState.PutString(KEY_OUTSTATE, dataGotFromServer);
    }
```

I tried here to restore but could not get it

```
 public override void OnViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            var result = savedInstanceState.GetString(KEY_OUTSTATE, dataGotFromServer);
        }

    }
```

and also I tried on ***CreateView(), OnActivityCreated() and On Create()*** but unsuccessfull to restore.

And my code for fragment replacement is as

```
 public void ReplaceFragment(Context context, Fragment newFragment, string TAG)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).SupportFragmentManager;
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, newFragment);
        ft.AddToBackStack(TAG);
        ft.Commit();

    }
```

Edited: 
This is how I call this fragment

```
 case (Resource.Id.nav_attendance):


                var role = session.GetUserDetails().Get(SessionManagement.KEY_ROLE).ToString();
                if (role=="Student")
                {
                    Fragment attendanceTabFragment = new AttendanceTabFragment();
                    customFragment.ReplaceFragment(this, attendanceTabFragment,typeof(AttendanceTabFragment).Name);
                }else
                {
                    Fragment attendanceFragment = new AttendanceFragment();
                    customFragment.ReplaceFragment(this, attendanceFragment, typeof(AttendanceFragment).Name);
                }
```

Any idea or sample code much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please look [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949274/saving-and-restoring-state-using-fragments] this link.

Comment: Can you add how you calling `ReplaceFragment`?

Comment: When do you expect it to restore? Please describe what user does, what you expect to happen, and what happens?

Comment: I have menu option named Attendance on Navigation Drawer and its click event maintained in activity then user lands on this fragment. So, first time its fine to call webserver to pull data afterwards if user clicks on this option, I would like to restore data rather than calling again webserver.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have edited code for your reference.

Comment: You are not restoring Fragments, you keep in creating new ones and piling them on onto the backStack. You should be using FindFragmentByTag. I see that @SushiHangover has given you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the Activity that contains the Fragment get disposed, Fragment's `OnSaveInstanceState` is not going to be called.

In a situation were you are swapping Fragments in and out, using **`Fragment.Arguments`** is an option instead of a singleton/static var...

re: [getArguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()) / [setArguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle))

In using arguments:

1. Create a new Bundle in the Fragment constructor  and assign it to
   `Arguments`
2. In the `OnPause` override update the Arguments/Bundle
   with the items you need to save.
3. In the `OnResume` override read the
   Arguments/Bundle items that you need to restore.

Example Fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{
    public Fragment1(System.IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        CreateArgumentBundle();
    }

    public Fragment1()
    {
        CreateArgumentBundle();
    }

    void CreateArgumentBundle()
    {
        Arguments = new Bundle();
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Frag1, container, false);
    }

    public override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        Arguments.PutString("someKey", "StackOverflow");
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        var someKeyString = Arguments.GetString("someKey", "someDefaultString(new bundle)");
        Log.Debug("SO", someKeyString);
    }
}
```

In your `ReplaceFragment` make sure that you are assigning the `TAG` in the `Replace` call:

```
public void ReplaceFragment(Context context, Fragment newFragment, string TAG)
{
    SupportFragmentManager
        .BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, newFragment, TAG)
        .AddToBackStack(TAG)
        .Commit();
}
```

Before calling your `ReplaceFragment`, check to see if the Fragment exists (`FindFragmentByTag`) before creating a new one, this example just swaps two fragments in and out and only creates new ones if the manager does not contain one:

```
button.Click += delegate
{
    toggle = !toggle;
    var frag = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(toggle ? "frag1" : "frag2");
    frag = frag ?? ( toggle ? (Fragment)new Fragment1() : (Fragment)new Fragment2() );
    ReplaceFragment(this, frag, toggle ? "frag1" : "frag2");
};
```

Note: You will still need to handle the other Fragment lifecycle events in the case that the hosting Activity is recycled:

- [Fragment LifeCycles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)